# Uncontrolled Copy if Printed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word, footer

How do i automatically add `Uncontrolled Copy if Printed` footer onto a word document approved in sharepoint? Any pointers will be helpful. Hidden text dosen't work as suggested by some blogs.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is Information Rights Management implemented in SharePoint:
https://blogs.office.com/2012/11/09/whats-new-with-information-rights-management-in-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online/

Comment: I have gone through multiple blogs on this topic as you have suggested. I still can't make heads or tail of my current problem. Kindly expound a bit further on what i need to do.